# Why after git rebase should do : git add?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Why after git rebase should do : "git add changedfile"?

More explanation for my Question:

1. add command taking file to staging not commit him
2. What git rebase --continue doing?

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to be about stopping mid-rebase, not what happens *after* a rebase. Is this correct? Is git prompting you to type `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: 2. I am asking not because something don't work - its works but i don't understand how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Git is telling you to type `git rebase --continue`, it's because the rebase isn't finishing. It sounds like you're stopping mid-rebase because of one or more conflicted files.

When you are in a conflicted state, you can type `git status` and look for "Unmerged paths" and files marked as "both modified":

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      README
```

Git is asking you to manually resolve the conflicted file, remove the change markers, and then `git add <file>` to mark the conflict resolved. This moves the changes into the staging area, telling Git to include them in the rebased commit which it will generate when the rebase continues.

Once you've done this, you can continue rebasing with `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: I dont understend : git add file -> to staging, but what put this file to commit?

Comment: Git puts the file into the commit. That's what staging the file does. When you rebase, Git is generating commits for you. When there is a conflict, Git asks you to resolve the conflict and then stage the files for it to commit so it can continue rebasing.